# What process happens in an IT nuclear decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, radiation

I've been researching medical isotopes and alot of them decay by an IT path. Does anyone know what IT stands for? And what physical process is happening?

Example: http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/getbandplot.jsp?unc=nds

Band 2 decays by IT 99.99% of the time

Comment: This is covered in the answer below, but, just in case:   http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistryglossary/g/Isomeric-Transition-Definition.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those curious I was able to find an answer. IT stands for Isomeric Transition. A metastable state emits a photon to decay to a lower energy

List of decay modes:
http://ie.lbl.gov/education/decmode.html

Comment: Some people prefer "internal transition".